# Tablayout inside Viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I need to place `TabLayout` in `ViewPager`. `ViewPager` contains some fragments. I can't do it because `TabLayout` is located in my `Activity` and I can't manage it if it will be in `Fragment`.
Now my code looks like this. In `Activity`'s XML:

```
 <LinearLayout
     ...>
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            ...>
         </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
         <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            .../>
 </LinearLayout>
```

and in `Activity` class

```
ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager_offer_detail);
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabDots);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager, true);
FragmentPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(...);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

I need to get as shown below.

[what i want](http://dropmefiles.com/hcwWO) (imgur doesn't work now)

Which version is correct and how to implement it in XML?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand, you want to show some `tabs` (`Fragments`) inside your `ViewPager` right?

you can follow this implementation in your fragment:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tablayout, container, false);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Campusplan"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Raumplan"));
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter
                (getFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount()));
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        return inflatedView;
    }

    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        int mNumOfTabs;

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
            super(fm);
            this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    TabItem1 tab1 = new TabItem1();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    TabItem1 tab2 = new TabItem1();
                    return tab2;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mNumOfTabs;
        }
    }
}
```

Put the tablayout and viewpager inside your layout.xml that represents your fragment as you do with a normal view.

Comment: No, i want to place Tablayout inside Viewpager. See link. And it tablayout must control outer Viewpager.